# I keep getting gunned down by an invisible sentry

Tags: team-fortress-2

In TF2 (in the 2014 Halloween map, where I have to deliver the tickets, for what it's worth), I keep getting destroyed  by a mini-sentry, but when I die, instead of zooming in on the sentry that killed me, the camera zooms in on what appears to be an invisible sentry. I've tried launching rockets at this thing, but it was to no avail. Is there any way to destroy these invisible sentries?

Comment: Sounds like some bug with your graphics card processing the sentry.

Comment: Does it zoom out-of-bounds? Like, it zooms into a wall? Because there are at least two ways to get out-of-bounds as an engineer on sd_doomsday_event.

Comment: @Unionhawk Yes- it zooms into a wall where the sentry should be.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is was only a bug that existed during a special event on a certain map that was fixed a week later on an online-only game so no one else should ever experience it again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a bug that was allowing people to build sentries outside the bounds of the map.

Supposedly this was fixed in [today's update](http://www.teamfortress.com/post.php?id=14869):

> Updated sd_doomsday_event
>
> Fixed players using the tiny-melee-only curse to get outside of the playable area of the map

Comment: i abused that glitch until its death.